# foreach (xmlNode) only inserts the first value

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, infopath

I'm attempting to insert values from an `MS Infopath` repeating table into a `SQL server DB` using a web service, but only the first value gets inserted and duplicated depending on how many rows there are.

**InfoPath**

[image: Form]

[image: Fields]

**SQL Server DB**

[image: Insert Result]

**Code**

```
[WebMethod]
public void SubmitDocument(XmlDocument doc)
{
    string firstname;
    string lastname;

    XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsManager.AddNamespace("my", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2018-08-16T17:55:49");
    nsManager.AddNamespace("dfs", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution");

    XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList list = root.SelectNodes("/dfs:IPDocument/my:myFields/my:UserList/my:Users", nsManager);

    foreach (XmlNode node in list)
    {
        firstname = node.SelectSingleNode("/dfs:IPDocument/my:myFields/my:UserList/my:Users/my:FirstName", nsManager).InnerText;
        lastname = node.SelectSingleNode("/dfs:IPDocument/my:myFields/my:UserList/my:Users/my:LastName", nsManager).InnerText;

        SubmitToDatabase(firstname, lastname);
    }
}

public void SubmitToDatabase(string firstname, string lastname)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO infopathconcepttable(FirstName, LastName)VALUES(@FirstName,@LastName)", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastname);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use `firstname = node.SelectSingleNode(".//my:FirstName", nsManager).InnerText;`?

Comment: Hi Colin, thank you very much for taking the time to look at my question, this works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has to do with providing an absolute XPath expression in your `SelectSingleNode()` call.

Try relacing the two `SelectSingleNode()` calls with the following lines:

```
firstname = node["FirstName", nsManager.LookupNamespace("my")].InnerText;
lastname = node["LastName", nsManager.LookupNamespace("my")].InnerText;
```

Comment: Hi Md, thanks for the taking the time to look at my question. This gives,  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: No problem. Looks like you found your answer in @colin-young's comment. If you do care to try my answer again, perhaps it will work as edited. It may not have found the node due to lack of namespace reference (added in edited answer).

Comment: Hi MD, thanks again the edited version works too. I will mark it as a solution seeing how Colin commented.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have already accessed your XmlNodeList, you don't need to re-specify the node you wish to acquire in your loop. 
If you're sure you won't get null values in your source, something like the following should give you the results you expect:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in list)
{
    firstname = node.SelectSingleNode("FirstName").InnerText;
    lastname = node.SelectSingleNode("LastName").InnerText;

    SubmitToDatabase(firstname, lastname);
}
```

You can also access the nodes from a nodelist by index:

```
firstname = node["FirstName"].InnerText;
lastname = node["LastName"].InnerText;
```

Comment: Sharp, thanks for taking the time to look at my question. Both suggestions, give  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: The above was not meant to be a "copy-paste" solution. But I believe you have already found the answer you were looking for with Colin's question.